# How to bind listbox items using observable colletion in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

My Code:

```
 ObservableCollection<SampleCheckedData> interestrates = new ObservableCollection<SampleCheckedData>();
 XDocument xmlDocu = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result)));

                interestrates = (from rts in xmlDocu.Descendants("Friend")

                                 select new SampleCheckedData
                                 {

                                     Id = (string)rts.Element("userid"),
                                     Name = (string)rts.Element("name"),
                                     Icon = (string)rts.Element("imageurl"),
                                     VisibleStatus = (string)rts.Element("visiblestatus"),
                                     AppStatus = (string)rts.Element("loginstatus"),

                                     imgBubble =bitmapRed,
                                 }).ToList<SampleCheckedData>();
```

Then Getting Error as can't implicitly convert system.collection.generic.list to system.collection.observablecollection like that.How to bind listbox items using observable collection?

EDIT:

```
Button b = sender as Button;
                    var res = interestrates.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)(e.OriginalSource)).Tag)).ToList();
                    if (res.Count == 1)
                        interestrates.Remove(res.First());
                    interestrates = new ObservableCollection<SampleCheckedData>();
                    lstFriendRequuest.ItemsSource = "";
                    bindGetFriends();
```

Here successfully deleting item from list but after   calling bindGetFriends() in that binding the items newly then   i am not getting new items getting old items.why the service returning old items list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this extension:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        foreach (var item in collection) observableCollection.Add(item);
        return observableCollection;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
interestrates = (from rts in xmlDocu.Descendants("Friend") 
    select new SampleCheckedData
    {    
        Id = (string)rts.Element("userid"),
        Name = (string)rts.Element("name"),
        Icon = (string)rts.Element("imageurl"),
        VisibleStatus = (string)rts.Element("visiblestatus"),
        AppStatus = (string)rts.Element("loginstatus"),    
        imgBubble =bitmapRed,
    }).ToObservableCollection<SampleCheckedData>();
```

Comment: giving error ToObservableCollection does not conatin a definition for it.

Comment: i added above static class but giving error as not conatin ToObservableCollection

Comment: The posted codes is called "extension method" and has to be available where you want to use it. Make sure you dont miss a "using"

Comment: Why listbox not refreshing the items .please tell me..please check my edit code.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Observable collection to List,

```
List<SampleCheckedData> interestrates = new List<SampleCheckedData>();
```

You can also bind List to ListBox, instead of ObservableCollection

And to solve your other problem of deleting selected item from listbox, try the following code:

```
 var selectedIndex = listbox.SelectedIndex;
 var listItems = listbox.ItemsSource as List<SampleCheckedData>;
 listItems.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
 listbox.ItemsSource = null;
 listbox.ItemsSource = listItems;
```

If still you are facing problems, let me know

Comment: By using listbox i am facing listbox is not refreshing when deletion of  item from that listbox.so that using observable collection.

Comment: How to bind listbox items using observable collection?

Comment: listItems.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);getting parameter index error.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting? In debugging, try to find whether the value of the selectedIndex is correct or not

Comment: getting selectedindex value as -1.

Comment: Button b = sender as Button ;
  var emp = interestrates.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)(e.OriginalSource)).Tag)).ToList();
   if (emp.Count == 1)
                interestrates.Remove(emp.First());

Comment: By using above code deleting item but not refreshing the listbox with.listbox.ItemsSource = null;
 listbox.ItemsSource = listItems;